# Is the function $\ g(n)\ $ defined for every positive integer $\ n\ $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Define $$f(m):=m\mod \varphi(m)$$ where $\ \varphi(m)\ $ denotes the totient function.

Now define $\ g(n)\ $ to be the smalles positive integer $\ m\ $ with $\ f(m)=n\ $ , if such a positive integer exists and undefined , if no such integer exist.

> Is $\ g(n)\ $ defined for every positive integer $\ n\ $?

I calculated $\ g(n)\ $ upto $\ n=3\cdot 10^4\ $. The largest value that appeared was $$g(23455)=3796759$$ and $\ g(n)\ $ is actually defined upto this limit.

Comment: Calculate the first few values, and then consult the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, oeis.org

Comment: Following the *Gerry Myerson*'s suggestion, we find http://oeis.org/A234642 with the comments "Conjecture: $a(n) > 0$ for all $n$. This would follow from a form of Goldbach's (binary) conjecture. Checked up to $10^7$; largest term in that range is $a(9972987) = 4178506411$.

Pomerance proves that $x \equiv n \pmod {\phi(x)}$ has at least two solutions for each $n$, but this allows $x < n$ and so does not prove the conjecture above.

$a(n) > 0$ for all $ n \le 10^9$. The largest term in that range is $a(990429171) = 1050844225771$. - Donovan Johnson, Feb 18 2014 "

Comment: @Hagen, maybe you'd like to post that as an answer.